# Filtering Object from DevTool console (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, devtools

[image: this is the response i want to filter :]

Im using an API called govmap https://api.govmap.gov.il/#intersect-features , this is the function that sending the response to the devtool:

> THIS FUNCTION IS IN <-head-> -->  on index.html

```
 function showExample() {
            var params = {
                type: govmap.locateType.lotParcelToAddress,
                address: 'jerusalem 21, tel aviv'
            }
            govmap.searchAndLocate(params).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }
```

I want to filter the response (screenshot added with picture at the beggining)
so the output will only INCLUDES Values who's in data .

any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried console logging response.data?

Comment: yes i tried , i did response.type  to know the object type the output is Undifined , and response.data not an exists function.

Comment: Have you tried doing `.catch` to see if there's any error? The use is `func().then().catch(e => console.log(e))`. Because if the API requires JSON, you usually need to stringify the params by `JSON.stringify(params)`. Also, `response.data` is not a function, but it's an attribute of Object `response`.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the object has no property with the bane type. But it does has a property named data.
On the last lines you have a function (response){
Console.log(response)}
On that console log when you write response.data does it shows undefined?

Comment: @DhanaD.  there is no need JSON.strngify(params) and yes i did .catch i see now the error  and i fixed .

Comment: @EAzevedo response.data now shows  the data . but how i filter Values?

Comment: So it's solved already?

Comment: @DhanaD. the response.data query now works but still i need to filter the values Array .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Based on key how to filter from array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416652/based-on-key-how-to-filter-from-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @DhanaD. not exactly , as i see he filters the email from the array but i dont have something to filter with i just want to see only Values in console (response.data[0].Values) works!!

Comment: response.data is an array with one element. It looks like an object with three properties: created, isEdited, objectId and another array with two values.

response.data[0] will give you just that array.
response.data[0].values should give you just the array with the two items (5387 and 48)